# Select rows that are equal to different values in awk

Tags: awk

I have a data frame whose first column has representative numbers of animal breeds like that:

```
1 12M08413 12M08388 12M08414 1 -9 A A G G G G
1 12M08416 12M08412 12M08415 1 -9 A A A G G G
1 12M08422 12M08397 12M08421 1 -9 A A A G G G
2 12M08423 12M08395 12M08396 2 -9 A A G G G G
2 12M08424 12M08392 12M08425 1 -9 A A A G G G
2 12M08426 12M08399 12M08411 1 -9 A A G G G G
3 12M08428 12M08400 12M08403 2 -9 A A G G G G
3 12M08434 12M08410 12M08417 1 -9 A A G G G G
4 12M08435 12M08389 12M08394 1 -9 A A A G G G
4 12M08437 12M08390 12M08427 1 -9 A A A G G G
```

I would like to get the rows that are equal to 1 or 3 in the first column. For example:

```
1 12M08413 12M08388 12M08414 1 -9 A A G G G G
1 12M08416 12M08412 12M08415 1 -9 A A A G G G
1 12M08422 12M08397 12M08421 1 -9 A A A G G G
3 12M08428 12M08400 12M08403 2 -9 A A G G G G
3 12M08434 12M08410 12M08417 1 -9 A A G G G G
```

I have done:

`awk -F, '$1 == c("1","3")' my_file.txt`

But `c(...)` isn't correct. How I can do this?

Comment: Just curious, where did you get the `c(...)` idea?

Comment: It should be simple, `awk '$1==1 || $1==3' file` in your case with shown samples. This simply looks if 1st field is either `1` OR `3` then print that line. Also you need not to use `-F,` part since that is for setting field separator to comma and you don't have comma separated lines.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha I was really testing if it would be written similar to the command in R

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, it worked properly. If you write it as an answer I will select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '$1==1 || $1==3' Input_file
```

***Explanation with OP's attempt fix:*** This simply looks if 1st field is either 1 OR 3 then print that line. Also you need not to use `-F,` part since that is for setting field separator to comma and you don't have comma separated lines.

Answer (score 3):

Perfect answer from RavinderSingh13!

I probably would have used a regular expression (see comment from @Daweo):

```
awk '$1~/^[13]$/' Input_File
```

Comment: `$1~/[13]/` does work for shown input samples, but beware that it will be true for any `$1` with `1` or `3` inside, so if there will be records with `10` in first field they will be printed too. If you have to use regular expression for that make sure it is spanning whole column width i.e. do `awk '$1~/^[13]$/' Input_File`

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in possible close to R solution: so far I know `AWK` do not have Doppelganger of `R`'s vectors created using `c(...)`, but there exist *associative* arrays i.e. holding key-value pairs, which support `in` check. `in` is true if given key exists, so your task might be accomplished following way, let `file.txt` be:

```
1 12M08413 12M08388 12M08414 1 -9 A A G G G G
1 12M08416 12M08412 12M08415 1 -9 A A A G G G
1 12M08422 12M08397 12M08421 1 -9 A A A G G G
2 12M08423 12M08395 12M08396 2 -9 A A G G G G
2 12M08424 12M08392 12M08425 1 -9 A A A G G G
2 12M08426 12M08399 12M08411 1 -9 A A G G G G
3 12M08428 12M08400 12M08403 2 -9 A A G G G G
3 12M08434 12M08410 12M08417 1 -9 A A G G G G
4 12M08435 12M08389 12M08394 1 -9 A A A G G G
4 12M08437 12M08390 12M08427 1 -9 A A A G G G
```

then

```
BEGIN{a["1"]=a["3"]=""}($1 in a){print}
```

output

```
1 12M08413 12M08388 12M08414 1 -9 A A G G G G
1 12M08416 12M08412 12M08415 1 -9 A A A G G G
1 12M08422 12M08397 12M08421 1 -9 A A A G G G
3 12M08428 12M08400 12M08403 2 -9 A A G G G G
3 12M08434 12M08410 12M08417 1 -9 A A G G G G
```

Explanation: I create array with keys `"1"` and `"3"` both holding empty string named `a`, then for every line in which first column is present I `print` it.